# Mysql query containing a php array key? ie. "WHERE profession = $user['profession'] "

Tags: php, mysql

How do i deal with something like this:

```
"SELECT skills FROM jobs WHERE profession = $user['profession']"
```

where profession is a string...

Comment: What type is `profession` of?

Comment: `@alexn` Haroldo wrote that it is a string.

Comment: where profession is a string...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use

```
"SELECT skills FROM jobs WHERE profession = '{$user['profession']}'"
```

PHP allows you to mix quotation marks like that

**Note** Assuming all the security checks and validations are done before this bit

Comment: ah, never knew you could do that!

Comment: Cool. Just to reiterate. **Please do sanitize your strings before you put them into your queries**. At the very least `mysql_real_escape_string`

Comment: haha, yep, I've got loads of sanitization validation happening before this stage. It would seem mental/messy to me to start putting santization inside the actual query as some have suggested.

Comment: Read more about the curly syntax here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Answer (score 2):

Another alternate way

```
"SELECT skills FROM jobs WHERE profession = 
'".mysql_real_escape_string($user['profession'])."'";
```

If you don't need `mysql_real_escape_string()` just remove it.

```
 "SELECT skills FROM jobs WHERE profession ='".$user['profession']."'";
```

Comment: Am i missing something, why is everyone telling me to put `mysql_real_escape_string()` in my query!!!?

Comment: @Haroldo They are not telling you that you MUST put it at that exact place, they are just reminding you to mysql_escape every time you put something in a query. And they are reminding everyone else who have the same question and find this thread later.

Answer (score 0):

```
$profession = mysql_real_escape_string( $user['profession'] );
$query = 'SELECT skills FROM jobs WHERE profession = "' . $profession . '"';
```

Comment: I'm not looking to sanitize, just insert an array value without reassinging to a var